# checkbox value displaying twice

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, arrays, jquery-selectors

I am using jquery to get the value of a checkbox. However, what is happening is that the value is getting duplicated and seems to be getting values for all checkboxes in the while loop. I would be grateful if someone could point out my error. Thank you.

UPDATE: Current code. Now only selecting first entry. No output on further checkbox clicks.

PHP Code

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) 
{
    $ticket = $row['ticket_frm'];
    $rowdate = date("d/m/Y",strtotime($row['date_frm']));
    $id = $row['id_frm'];
    $from = $row['from_frm'];
    $subject = $row['subject_frm'];
    $message = $row['message_frm'];

    $myString = <<<EOF
    <span><input id="check" type="checkbox" name="delete" value="<?php echo $ticket ?>"></span>
    <div class='msgTrue buttonMailTrue' data-message='%s' data-subject='%s' data-rowdate='%s' data-from='%s'>

    <img src="images/sml_new_mail_icon.gif" class="mailIcon" alt="" />$subject;
    <div class="rowdate">$rowdate</div><br />
    <span class="mailFrom">$from</span>
    </div>
    <p class="checked"></p>
    <!-- The following end tag need to be at the start of the line -->
    EOF;
    printf($myString, $message, $subject, $rowdate, $from);
}   echo '<p class="checked">'.'</p>';
```

jQuery Code

```
$(function() {
    $("#check").click(function() {
       var isChecked = $(this).prop("checked");  // or $(this).prop("checked")
         if (isChecked) {
           $("p.checked").html("Checkbox is checked: <b>True</b>");
       } else {
           $("p.checked").html("Checkbox is checked: <b>False</b>");
}
```

});
});

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According your code and selectors, there are many `input class="check"` elements on your page.
You find them by class name, so this is why they are duplicate.

Use `id`-attribute and `$("#id")` syntax to get right values, or use `this` keyword in your code:

```
//var isChecked = $('.check').is(':checked'); - wrong
var isChecked = $(this).is(':checked'); // right
```

**Update:**
You didn't provide unique `id` for your elements. Of cause this doesn't work. Your error is the same as earlier.
Try this code:

```
<input id="check$ticket" type="checkbox" name="delete" value="<?php echo $ticket ?>">
```

Same for javascript - you have to find element by it's unique `id`

```
  $("#check" + TICKET_NUMBER_HERE).click(function() {
   var isChecked = $(this).prop("checked");  // or $(this).prop("checked")
     if (isChecked) {
       $("p.checked").html("Checkbox is checked: <b>True</b>");
   } else {
       $("p.checked").html("Checkbox is checked: <b>False</b>");
```

Comment: It is still returning duplicate values. If it makes a difference, I am testing against ie6/7.

Comment: @user1532468 Bring us the simplified Html with your input so we can test it.

Comment: @VM I changed from class to ID as per your original suggestion.

Comment: @user1532468 You still have to provide unique `id` for your elements.

Comment: @VM The only element I am trying to get value for is #check. What over id's do I need to assign. Thanks

Comment: @user1532468 How many input type='check' do you have on page?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19830/discussion-between-vmatm-and-user1532468)

Comment: In your line: $("#check" + TICKET_NUMBER_HERE).click(function() { how do i get ticket number here?

Comment: @user1532468 From your database, of cause. Look, we won't write whole code for you. You got the answer about problem you've met. It's up to you how to resolve it.

Comment: That is not what I meant. I am using your suggested code and in that code you changed the id to id="check$ticket" and in your jquery you put TICKET NUMBER HERE. I don't understand how to get $ticket from php to jQuery. I had already written the code and have never asked for you to write the code. In future, I suggest if you make a suggestion and someone doesn't understand your answer, have the decency to explain to the user. That dosen't imply writing the code for them. Thanks for your previous help.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `this` to *work* with current checkbox:

```
$(".check").click(function() {
    var isChecked = this.checked;  // or $(this).prop("checked")
    if (isChecked) {
        $("p.checked").html("Checkbox is checked: <b>True</b>");
    } else {
        $("p.checked").html("Checkbox is checked: <b>False</b>");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your jquery code to. As  $('.check') returns array of object it is by default checking property of 1st object only

```
$(function() {
  $('.check').click(function(){
    var isChecked = $(this).is(':checked');
    alert(isChecked);
    if(isChecked)
      $('p.checked').html('Checkbox is checked: <b>True</b>');
    else
      $('p.checked').html('Checkbox is checked: <b>False</b>');
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
$(".check").click( function() { 
    $("p.checked").html( 
        "Checkbox is checked: <b>" + $(this).is(":checked") + "</b>" );
}
```